# Exclude Jekyll posts from output (don't output individual HTML files)

Tags: jekyll

Since I list all my posts in one page called `fotos.html` I don't need the individual posts to appear as HTML files in the `_site` output directory. How can I tell Jekyll to not output the `.md` posts in the `_posts` directory as individual HTML files?

[[image: Screenshot of the Jekyll output directory]

E.g. The contents of `Firmwochenende.html` are present in `fotos.html` with properly formatted title and date. `Firmwochenende.html` includes only photos and nothing else, which is not useful at all.

I build using `build exec jekyll serve` and host on Github Pages: https://github.com/junge-pfarre/junge-pfarre.github.io

These are the relevant parts of `_config.yml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
  - scope:
      path: "assets/flyer"
    values:
      flyer: true

markdown: kramdown

permalink: :title
```

A simple post has these contents:

```
---
title: Jugendandacht Gründonnerstag
---
![Altar der Josefskapelle in der Pfarrkirche Baden St. Stephan][1]

[1]: {{ site.baseurl }}{% link /assets/fotos/Jugendandacht2018.jpg %}
```

Comment: `exclude: [_posts]` in `_config.yml` doesn't work, btw.

Comment: You can create a [data](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) file with a list of your photos with titles, then display them using a special template that loads your data file at `fotos.html`.

Comment: Will I still be able to use pagination then? Or would I have to come up with my own pagination solution then?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a custom collection rather than the default as the `_posts` collection is, [by design](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5906), always going to output individual files. If you create a new collection, you can specify `output: false` for that collection in your config file while still being able to iterate through it and display the content. From the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#setup):

```
# Config file

collections:
  your_collection_name:
    output: false
```

However, I saw that you mentioned pagination in the comments. I don't believe GitHub currently supports a gem that has pagination functionality for collections other than `_posts` (like jekyll-paginate-v2, though [they're in talks](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/9) on merging this in eventually). In the meantime, it looks like there are [some solutions out there](https://gist.github.com/Phlow/5613fb3f18946f577f071e2a258749a3) to help with this limitation.